# Can I subtract dates to see if token valid?

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating an email verification token and saving it along with a date the token was created in my MongoDB.

I was wondering (instead of checking this in my node.js API - and making 2 calls to the DB) is it possible to do in one? How do I say if input date is less than 24 hours of date in the database?

So at the moment, I do the update bit (if the IDs match using)

```
User.update({$and:[ {theID: userID}, {verifyID: emailID} ] },
            {$set: {verified: true} })
```

So in that `$and` block I want to add the date part if it's possible.

Comment: You don't need the `$and`, it's implicit.

Comment: Ok - wasnt aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a *Date* with the match query, use the `$gt` operator

```
var since = new Date();
since.setDate(since.getDate() - 1);

User.update(
    {
        theID: userID,
        verifyID: emailID,
        Date: {$gt: since}
    },
    {$set: {verified: true}}
);
```